# Spring-boot log rotations issue with logback

Tags: spring, logging, logback

I am working on a spring-boot project and I am using logback and slf4j for logging. Application is deployed on external tomcat and I am using logback 1.1.6 .
I have created an appender with marker , it working fine but rotation policy is not working.

here is the entry from logback.xml

```
   <appender name="FAILED-QUERY"
            class="com.xyz.config.HourlyFileAppender">
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">   
          <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.OnMarkerEvaluator">
            <marker>FAILEDQUERY</marker>
          </evaluator>
         <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
         <onMatch>NEUTRAL</onMatch>
       </filter>
            <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                <Pattern>
                    %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
                </Pattern>
            </encoder>

            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <!-- rollover daily -->
                <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/xyz_otp_logs_failed_query.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log
                            </fileNamePattern>

                <!-- <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">

                </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy> -->
            </rollingPolicy>

        </appender>

      <logger name="com.xyz" level="info"
        additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FAILED-QUERY" />
        <!--    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> -->
        </logger>
```

The code for rotating policy is below

```
public class HourlyFileAppender<E> extends RollingFileAppender<E> {
     private static long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); // minutes
     private int rollOverTimeInSecond = 60*60;
    @Override
       public void rollover()
       {
          long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
          int maxIntervalSinceLastLoggingInMillis = rollOverTimeInSecond * 1000;

          if ((currentTime - start) >= maxIntervalSinceLastLoggingInMillis)
          {
             super.rollover();
             start = System.currentTimeMillis();
          }
       }

}
```

though the same settings for other appender is working fine.

Comment: For rollover to occur, in addition to rollover conditions, a log message has to get through. The OnMarkerEvaluator might be preventing this.

Comment: @Ceki  I am using same appender with name change for opposite case when match occurs the don't print the log and if match not occurs then it print the log and it is rotating fine.
<onMismatch>NEUTRAL</onMismatch>
<onMatch>DENY</onMatch>